# PHP preg_replace Regex dont replace when cid: until next match

Tags: php, regex

So basicly I am trying to make a Regex where it looks for `src=""`, skips it when it's like `src="cid:` and goes to the next match with an interval of 1.

Here is my full line of code right now:

```
$mailMessage = preg_replace( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , 'src="cid:' . $imageCombined . '" ' . 'id="' . $imageID . '"' , $mailMessage , 1);
```

The `@src="([^"]+)"@` is the part that I am referring to.

Comment: Note that using double-quoted strings (`"src=\"cid:$imageCombined\"id=\"$imageID\""`) you can avoid some of that concatenation in the question, which may make code easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
'@src="(?!cid:)([^"]+)"@'
       ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQhawL/1).

**Details**

- `src="` - literal text `src="`
- `(?!cid:)` - a [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is `cid:` string immediately to the right of the current location
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a `"` char
- `"` - a `"` char.